# Ruby fast and fuzzy search array of lots of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, search, hash

I have an array of hashes like this

```
@t = [{"id"=>"819827", "nm"=>"Razvilka", "countryCode"=>"RU"}, 
{"id"=>"524901", "nm"=>"Moscow", "countryCode"=>"RU"}, 
{"id"=>"1271881", "nm"=>"Firozpur Jhirka", "countryCode"=>"IN"}, 
{"id"=>"1283240", "nm"=>"Kathmandu", "countryCode"=>"NP"}] # ... + 100,000 more
```

I can search from a particular hash key with exact spelling like

```
@t.find {|x| x["nm"] == "Moscow"}
```

and it will return the hash decently quick.

But this wont account for casing, grammar or approximate match. How can I do that?

Comment: define _grammar or approximate match_.

Comment: If it is spelled "moscow" or "mosc", or "MoScoV", etc, it should be able to return anything which matches?

Comment: The industry term for matching two strings that sound similar is a "soundex". Here's an El-Goog search for Ruby libraries that do it: https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+soundex

Comment: I think you should use a library (as suggested) rather than a diy job.

Comment: I am sure soundex(as suggested) would make it hard to work with this type of data. I don't know what kind or is there a library for searching through array of hashes?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/threedaymonk/text

Comment: Is there a ruby way to atleast handle word casing? The text can be entered in lowercase and the document might have a different case. Can the `find` method be hacked to return words irrespective of casing?

Comment: Regex perhaps, `@t.find {|x| x["nm"][/moscow/i] }` but like I say, can't be sure how durable it is. Also note `find` only returns the first match. Use `select` for all matches.

Comment: As much as I would like to be able to hand you a quick, pure-Ruby solution, have you considered loading this data to a database—even SQLite with Soundex enabled—and doing your fuzzy search there?

Comment: When you give an example use only valid Ruby objects (so readers can run their code against your example and show it gives the desired result--so no "....",), make it as short as possible (3 hashes, each with 3 key-value pairs) would be sufficient) and assign a variable to each input object (e.g., `arr = [{....]`), so that readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Edited.

Comment: @mwp I can give that a shot

Comment: @SagarPandya Yeah regex works though it may be not as fast considering the quantum of rows.

Answer (score 2):

Try levenshtein gem https://rubygems.org/gems/levenshtein

```
gem install levenshtein
```

then in your code:

```
require `levenshtein`

#Levenshtein.distance(a, b) < 5 # some fuzzy level

def find_levenshtein(hash, key, str)
  hash.select do |h|
    Levenshtein.distance(h[key], str) < 5
  end
end

puts find_levenshtein(t, 'nm', 'moscw').inspect
#=> [{"id"=>"524901", "nm"=>"Moscow", "lat"=>"55.752220", "lon"=>"37.615555", "countryCode"=>"RU"}]
```

For more info see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: Levenstshtein doesn't work always. While testing most of the time I had to keep changing the fuzzy level to get the expected result. So at the moment I am simple doing a regex search. I also tried the sim_string algorithm, that works to a good degree but not enough to challenge regex! I dont think a low overhead solution exists for fixing fuzziness.